# How to call and pass arguments to functions with spaces in unix

Tags: ksh

I'm creating a unix script that will call and pass arguments to function in unix. Once called, the function should identify how many parameters passed to it. I tried the normal way of calling and passing of arguments to function and it works. However, I noticed that the function is counting the arguments word by word and my problem on it is that, what if I have a single argument that contains spaces or a multiple arguments but some of it should be single argument but with spaces? Is it possible to identify by the function that the arguments specified should be considered as single argument? I already used double quotation and it didn't work.

Here is the relevant portion of my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

ARG_CNT() {
    SCRIPT_AR_CNT=$#
    if [ SCRIPT_AR_CNT -lt 3 ]; then
        echo "Error. Incorrect number of arguments specified."
        echo "Error. Execute \"./script_template.ksh -h\" for help."
        exit 1
    fi
}

echo "Specify the Arguments: "
read SCRIPT_AR
if [ "${SCRIPT_AR}" = "" ] || [ "${SCRIPT_AR}" = "." ]; then
    exit
else
    ARG_CNT $SCRIPT_AR
fi
```

Comment: Could you show your code please? Also, what language are you coding in? Bash?

Comment: `call_function(){ echo $#; }; call_function "1st word" 2nd 3rd` prints 3

Comment: You can then iterate (`for var in` ...) on `"$@"` (the quotes are vital), and you'll get the three arguments in succession.

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/ksh

ARG_CNT() {
    SCRIPT_AR_CNT=$#
 if [ SCRIPT_AR_CNT -lt 3 ]; then
     echo "Error. Incorrect number of arguments specified."
        echo "Error. Execute \"./script_template.ksh -h\" for help."
  exit 1
 fi
}

echo "Specify the Arguments: "
read SCRIPT_AR
if [ "${SCRIPT_AR}" = "" ] || [ "${SCRIPT_AR}" = "." ]; then
 exit
else
    ARG_CNT $SCRIPT_AR
fi`----the foregoing is a portion of my script.

Comment: @NonoTaps I edited your question to add that code in, and formatted it. In the future, please do that yourself.

Comment: @Schwern, thank you. I'm still a newbie here. :)

Comment: @PSkocik, I also tried using `for var in`... and it still reading the arguments word by word even there is a quotation enclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not quoting your variables:

```
ARG_CNT $SCRIPT_AR
```

If you don't quote regular variables, they'll be split on $IFS. You should only leave out quotes if you explicitly want this kind of splitting, and that should be rare (so comment it). Quoting also slightly improves performance.

```
ARG_CNT "$SCRIPT_AR"
```

If I may suggest more edits:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

arg_cnt() {
  #ALL_CAPS should be reserved to env variables (exported vars) and  shell config variables
    script_ar_cnt=$# 
    [ script_ar_cnt -lt 3 ] && {
        echo "Error. Incorrect number of arguments specified."
        echo "Error. Execute \"./script_template.ksh -h\" for help."
        exit 1
    } >&2 
}

echo "Specify the Arguments: "
read script_ar

ex_dataerr=65   # data format error 
{ [ -z "$script_ar" ] || [ "$script_ar" = "." ]; } && exit "$ex_dataerr"

arg_cnt "$script_ar"
```

Comment: I already quoted the variable SCRIPT_AR but it seems that the script is treating the whole arguments as 1 regardless of the number of arguments I've specified.

Comment: `script_ar` will be treated as one because you read it with one `read`. If you want script_ar split, not on $IFS, but like a shell would split it (with quotations and everything), then you want `eval "arg_cnt $script_ar"`.

Comment: No problem. Be careful with `eval`'s, though. Especially if your input is untrusted.